# How to convert provided number of hours into days hours minutes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, web

I have an input hours which will be 0 to any hours, for example

25 hours... I need an output in days hours and minutes: 1 day 1 hour 0 min

I have tried and it returns days but help me to convert to days hrs and min
var flag_hours = 25;

```
if(flag_hours >=24)
{
     var totaldays = flag_bookbefore/24;
     alert(totaldays);
}
```

which gives output as : `1.0416666666666667`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Math.floor(number)` returns the nearest integer. In your example it'll return 1 which is one day

Comment: Division will give you the number of days and for the rest you could use the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) to calculate the leftover hours and mins.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this function: It gives you access to days hours and minutes separately.

```js
function SplitTime(numberOfHours){
    var Days=Math.floor(numberOfHours/24);
    var Remainder=numberOfHours % 24;
    var Hours=Math.floor(Remainder);
    var Minutes=Math.floor(60*(Remainder-Hours));
    return({"Days":Days,"Hours":Hours,"Minutes":Minutes})
}

var hours=27.3
    var timeResult=SplitTime(hours)
    console.log("27.3 hours translate to  "+timeResult.Days+"Days "+timeResult.Hours+"Hours and "+timeResult.Minutes+"Minutes.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var days = Math.floor(flag_hours / 24);
var hours = Math.floor(flag_hours) % 24;
var minutes = (flag_hours - Math.floor(flag_hours)) * 60;
```

Not tested, might be horribly wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure how the modulo-operator works with non-integers, you might need to take that into account and slightly update the code. Other than that, I like this answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var hour = 47.5;
var day = 0;
var minute = parseInt((hour % 1)*60);
if (hour>24){
    day = parseInt(hour / 24);
    hour = parseInt(hour % 24);
}else{
    hour = parseInt(hour);
}
alert (day);
alert(hour);
alert(minute);
```

check it in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meyu86fc/6/)

Comment: If the provided hours are in integer form then yes, the minutes would always be zero. But if the input was as a decimal number, then you could convert. e.g 0.5 hours = 30 minutes

Comment: OP never said the input has to be integer, so no need to update the question